# Sending Goal from rosjava action client to roscpp action server

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
While sending goal from an action roscpp client to roscpp action server, I use
actionlib::SimpleActionClientmsg::AbcAction client("action_server_name",true); and then client.sendGoal(goal) sends goal to the "action_server_name". This works fine.
Now I have a "action_server_name" running, I want to send the goal through a rosjava action client node. How is it done? If anyone has already done it? Action server in roscpp and action client rosjava communication and sending receiving goal, please share it with me.
Thanks in advance.
regards,
safdar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28434/sending-goal-from-rosjava-action-client-to-roscpp-action-server/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-02-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is an actionlib implementation for rosjava in rosjava_core: https://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/actionlib_java/ and there are some examples buried in there, https://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/actionlib_java/src/tutorials/java/org/ros/actionlib/example/ but it isn't documented on the wiki yet.

There is a ticket [here](http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=74) for creating the documentation; you can comment or vote on it if you feel so inclined.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-02-26**:
Hi, thanks , but this I have already done this. Actually the problem is that the java action client does not connect with action serve using its name. It only connects if the action server is listening on /goal action topic. I want to connect with different action CPP serves from one java program.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-02-26**:
Looking at the java ActionClient source, that looks like a bug. Note that nodeName is written but never read in https://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/actionlib_java/src/main/java/org/ros/actionlib/client/ActionClient.java

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-02-27**:
Bug filed as http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=88

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2017-11-22**:
2017: there is code on github from [ernestmc](https://github.com/ernestmc/rosjava_actionlib) and a fork by [CentralLabFacilities](https://github.com/CentralLabFacilities/rosjava_actionlib)